# if statement not being implemented in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, operators

It seems, the if statement is not being called in the given program. The output says it's a consonant even if the input is a vowel.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char input[1];
  cout << "Enter an alphabet:\n";
  cin >> input;
  if (input == "a" || input == "e" || input == "i" || input == "o" || input == "u") {    
    cout << "It is a vowel";
  }
  else
    cout << "It is a consonant";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you can't give any kind of input, all input will lead writing out of bounds of your array. Secondly, you compare pointers that will never be the same. Perhaps you meant to read a single character (in which case `input` should be a `char`, not an array) and compare with character constant (like e.g. `'a'`)?

Comment: Character literals are enclosed in single quotes (e.g. `'a'`)!

Comment: Turn the compiler warnings on - live - https://godbolt.org/z/Wf9o7o7Wf

Answer (score 3):

First of all you don't need to use an array. And on top of that you should use single quotes, so you should have something like this :

```cpp
int main(){
    cout<<"Enter an alphabet:\n";
    char input;
    cin>> input;
    if (input=='a' || input=='e' || input=='i' || input=='o' || input=='u' ){
         cout<<"It is a vowel";
    }
    else 
        cout<<"It is a consonant";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changed it, and I have to admit it looks better, but still think single space is viable

Comment: @NeoRox Much better now. Downvote retracted. But single space indentation is very odd. TBH, I've never seen it before..

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks. But yeah, as today's IDE clearly show when those { } closes I'm used to work with single space. And you're not wrong, I'm the only one using it where I work.